# Как выполнить нецелочисленное деление с помощью div?

Tags: ассемблер

Можно ли как-то поделить например 4 на 5 с помощью div и получить 0.8? Мне сказали что можно, если объединить eax и edx, но либо я делаю что-то не так, либо это не помогает. Я вообще не понимаю как это сделать, если используя div сохраняется только целая часть числа и остаток.Обращался к чатгпт, он не помогает

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int number = 4;
    unsigned int result;
    unsigned int remainder;

    __asm {
        mov eax, number
        mov edx, eax
        shr edx, 16
        mov bx, 5
        div bx
        movzx eax, ax
        mov result, eax
        mov remainder, edx
    }

    printf("Result: %u\n", result);
    printf("Remainder: %u\n", remainder);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *и получить 0.8?* Интересно, в каком регистре и в каком виде ты хочешь получить такое значение...

Comment: Я сам не знаю, мне преподаватель сказал так сделать и все. У меня получилось 0.8 только с помощью костылей
```   
printf("Result with fraction: %d.%d\n", result, remainder * 10 / divisor);
```

Comment: Ну целочисленными операциями - примерно так как вы показали, если с точностью до 1 знака после запятой.

Comment: Если нужна большая точность - то в цикле делить остаток на 10, с остатком, пока остаток 0 не останется, или пока не будет максимальная нужная точность.

Answer (score 2):

У меня нет подходящего компилятора, поэтому код будет на C.

Требуется вычислить *n/m* с точностью *p* знаков после запятой.

1. Умножаем *n* на *10<sup>p</sup>* - после этого деление выдаст нужное количество знаков.
2. Добавляем к *n* половину *m* - после этого деление будет давать округлённый результат.
3. Делим *n* на *m*. Получится число в котором нужно отсчитать *p* знаков справа и напечатать их в качестве дробной части.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned n, m, p;

    scanf("%u%u%u", &n, &m, &p);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
        n *= 10;
    }
    n += m >> 1;
    unsigned q = n / m;

    printf("%u\n", q);
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc div.c
>
> $ echo 355 113 0 | ./a.out
> 3
>
> $ echo 355 113 1 | ./a.out
> 31
>
> $ echo 355 113 2 | ./a.out
> 314
>
> $ echo 355 113 3 | ./a.out
> 3142
>
> $ echo 355 113 4 | ./a.out
> 31416
>
> $ echo 355 113 5 | ./a.out
> 314159
>
> $ echo 355 113 6 | ./a.out
> 3141593
>
> $ echo 355 113 7 | ./a.out
> 31415929
> ```

Это способ склонен к переполнениям, обычно десятичные дроби печатают по-другому. Зато его легко переложить на ассемблер без использования строк.

Comment: Совпадения случайны?

Comment: @avp, нет. Это рациональное приближение пи. Я других-то дробей и не знаю.